# Why do these bit reversal implementations run at such different speeds?

Tags: python, performance, comparison

I needed a bit reversal function. I assumed the first implementation would be faster as it uses bit manipulation and does not need to convert between different datatypes. However, after testing with `timeit` , I found that the second implementation is significantly faster. Why is this the case?

```py
def mirror(number, bit_length):
    LtR_bit = 1
    RtL_bit = 2 ** (bit_length - 1)
    mirror = 0

    while RtL_bit:
        if number & RtL_bit:
            mirror |= LtR_bit
        LtR_bit <<= 1
        RtL_bit >>= 1

    return mirror
```

```py
def reverse_bits(number, bit_length): 
    binary = bin(number) 
    reverse = binary[-1:1:-1] 
    reverse = reverse + (bit_length - len(reverse)) * '0'

    return int(reverse, 2)
```

Comment: The first code does many individual operations, whereas the second just does a few bulk operations. What makes you think "using bit manipulation" could possibly offset doing many more operations?

Comment: Where are you timing code and timing results?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Because I figured converting an integer to a string, slicing it, concatenating some zeros, and converting it back to an integer would turn out to be way more operations "under the hood." Using bit manipulation, no large data structures are used and no datatype conversion needs to be done.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode using `IPython`'s `%timeit` with default settings, i got `1.69 µs ± 86.7 ns per loop` for `mirror`, and `634 ns ± 36.2 ns per loop` for `reverse_bits`, which is consistent with the observations mentioned in the question: the bit-bashing method takes nearly three times as long as the array- and string-based method on my setup.

Comment: I should clarify that I used `number=100, bit_length=8` in the timing experiment. @MisterMiyagi's point makes sense: you have a `while` loop in the bit-based method, which will slow your code down drastically. The other method is fully vectorized and so runs a bit closer to compiled speed.